# ¿Como puedo obtener las cookies de un sitio con Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, cookies

**Hola**

Estoy iniciando la automatización de tareas pero requiero obtener y guardar todas las **cookies** y mas importantes las de sesión, pero al momento de buscar la cookies por el método de **Selenium** `driver.manage().getCookies()` no me obtiene nada de nada. Solo la Cookie que yo cargo e incluso esta misma ni se muestra en las **cookies** del sitio al yo manualmente con la herramientas de desarrollador de **Firefox** buscar la **cookie** en el sitio esta no existe, pero **Selenium** la encuentra.

Este es mi código de inicio:

```
FirefoxOptions opts = new FirefoxOptions();
        opts.addArguments("-private");
        FirefoxDriver f = new FirefoxDriver(opts);   

driver = f;

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/rp/request-password-reset");
```

Mi código para cargar y obtener las cookies:

```
private void getCookies(){

    driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("hola","1"));

            for(Cookie ck : driver.manage().getCookies())
            {
                System.out.println(ck.getName());
            }

   System.out.println(driver.manage().getCookies().size());
}
```

Espero su apoyo estoy algo perdido perdido el búsqueda de soluciones y ya que soy nuevo en **Selenium**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hallé esta respuesta en el sitio en inglés:

`driver.manage().getCookies();` siempre tiene tamaño 0 en [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) e [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer).

sin embargo hallé este workaround, usando `executeScript`

```
Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();

if (cookies.size() == 0) { // Para soportar FF e IE
    String cookiesString = (String) driver.executeScript("return document.cookie");
    cookies = parseBrowserCookies(cookiesString);
}




private Set<Cookie> parseBrowserCookies(String cookiesString) {
    Set<Cookie> cookies = new HashSet<>();

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(cookiesString)) {
        return cookies;
    }

    Arrays.asList(cookiesString.split("; ")).forEach(cookie -> {
        String[] splitCookie = cookie.split("=", 2);
        cookies.add(new Cookie(splitCookie[0], splitCookie[1], "/"));
    });

    return cookies;
}
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55101097/6999690

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo y el metodo **driver.manage().addCookie()** es funcional en Firefox ??

Comment: debería segun  la pregunta que hicieron allí.